What are the effects of too many open cursors on MongoDB
I'm researching some performance issues in MongoDB and I'm trying to find out what are the performance effects of having too many open cursors (hundreds, thousands) per node in a MongoDB node. Also, what are the reasonable limits for this and how to enforce it ?

Open cursors should not have major impact on performance. Usually they are others ways to improve the performance.

So having 30k cursors open at the same time, with plenty of cpu still available, should not affect performance ?

Cursor is a server side component, and it requires resources (e.g., memory). Once opened they need to closed. Sometimes these are closed automatically and some are closed upon certain time. In case they are not closed (due to some issue) or being used by an application they can affect the performance of the server.
